# Mac - Emulate a (360) controller with second keyboard+mouse

Tags: mac, game-controller, steam

I've been trying to play Portal 2 with my brother on my Macbook.
I don't have Xbox or PS3 controllers, only Wii remotes (Which I don't want to use).
However, I do have extra keyboards and mice.

The only ways I've seen to do it were through GlovePIE which is a Windows only app. I have Wine installed, but I'm sure that that wouldn't work.

I'm also worried about the mouse aspect, but maybe it's possible!

Thanks in advance!